# Android AlertDialog with list crashes in Debug mode but not Release

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I've run into a bit of a strange problem.  I'm trying to display an `AlertDialog` with a list when the user presses a button.  The following code works perfectly when I execute the app on a device or emulator.  However, if I run the app under the debugger on either a device or emulator, the code causes an exception and we break into the debugger on `builder.show();`.

This is an issue because I'm trying to debug a branch that comes after selecting something from my list.  The debugger brings up `ViewGroup.class` when it breaks, though I can't tell you the specific line because I don't think I *quite* have the right android source.

Any thoughts on why this is crashing in debug?

Callback:

```
public View.OnClickListener selectCategoryClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

    final String[] categories = new String [] {"A","B","C"};

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyApp.this);
        builder.setTitle("Select a category");
        builder.setItems(categories, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Do something with which
                }
            });
        builder.show();
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Aaron try with MyApp.getParent() , may be you are using TabActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I *finally* got the right source code to align with the SDK version that I was using (thanks to http://blog.michael-forster.de/2008/12/view-android-source-code-in-eclipse.html?showComment=1299971635442#c3854025611409009224).  Once I found the line causing the issue the cause became immediately clear:

```
public View getChildAt(int index) {
    try {
        return mChildren[index];                     <---- Crash line
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I had set a break point on all `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s and forgot to remove it.  Now the code runs fine.

My stupid mistake, thanks guys for the comments.